# Ubuntu Mate: mate-panel window buttons appeear only if panel is set to expand

Tags: mate, window, panel

I'm trying Ubuntu Mate. I've used GNOME2 bfoire (like a decade or something ago), and I'm a bit puzzled about the mate-panel behavior.

I always configured GNOME2 to have the window buttons in the top panel and delete the lower panel. I think it used to be easier when I used GNOME2. The thing is, when panel option "expand" is disabled and mate-panel is filling the desktop width, window buttons are not shown. But hwne the panel is set to "exapnd", they appear only when not expanded, and the again are not shown when fully expanded.

I think this never happened to me in GNOME2.

By the way, being a long time XFCE user, I find it quite hard to find a list of elements in the panel. I can only add, but I don't see a list to move or delete. I think I'm missing something, somewhere. This is part of the issue, because I thnk this could be related to an invisible separator set to "expand" taking all the space.